# How do I convert int column into vector in rstudio?

Tags: rstudio

I'm trying to visualize a column and it's supposed to be a vector as far as I know but when I convert the column into a vector, the vector loses the number value in it and change into 'character'. Tried to convert into double and this happen. Is there any simple explanation what's happening here?

```
> new_df3$Triwulan.I..Jumlah.Tanaman.  
 [1] 52258   2000    2122829 285     0       14053   1038    37331   0       221402   
[11] 0       5245    10      0       0       52790   0       2633    251     30642    
[21] 1898    0       0       180     6200     
21 Levels:  0 10 1038 14053 180 1898 2000 2122829 221402 251 2633 285 ... Triwulan I
> as.vector(new_df3$Triwulan.I..Jumlah.Tanaman.)
 [1] "52258"   "2000"    "2122829" "285"     "0"       "14053"   "1038"    "37331"  
 [9] "0"       "221402"  "0"       "5245"    "10"      "0"       "0"       "52790"  
[17] "0"       "2633"    "251"     "30642"   "1898"    "0"       "0"       "180"    
[25] "6200"
> as.double(new_df3$Triwulan.I..Jumlah.Tanaman.)  
 [1] 16  8  9 13  2  5  4 15  2 10  2 17  3  2  2 18  2 12 11 14  7  2  2  6 19  
> c(new_df3$Triwulan.I..Jumlah.Tanaman.)  
 [1] 16  8  9 13  2  5  4 15  2 10  2 17  3  2  2 18  2 12 11 14  7  2  2  6 19
```

Comment: Hi .. judging from a first look you are looking at factors - the '21 Levels:'  are a good hint in that direction. So first run `str(new_df3)` to see what you are really dealing with here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depending on how you created your `new_df3` data.frame you could do a couple of things.

If you imported it from eg a .csv file - educated guess based on the horrendous length of your column names there you could try setting `stringsAsFactors` to false, since it seems that your import has interpreted numeric values as strings (could be anything like a bad character in one of the rows) which then gets turned into 'factors'. The reason you see the Levels mentioned in your output. 
Same goes for if you created your data.frame via `new_df3 <- data.frame(...)` there as well you can define the `stringsAsFactors` parameter.

quick solution to your problem could just be - you almost had it there:

```
as.numeric(as.vector(new_df3$Triwulan.I..Jumlah.Tanaman.))
```

which would cast the numeric looking characters `[1] "52258"   "2000"    "2122829" "285"     "0"` to numbers.